# Date Specific Criteria for Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that is gathering data from the 20th of last month to the 19th of this month and it seems to be working.

```
(DateTime >= 19+dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,getdate())-1,0)   
AND  DateTime <  18+dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,getdate()),0))
```

I now need to somehow modify it to meet the following...

Always show the current report no matter when it is run.

Currently what happens is.....it works great if run anytime between the 20th of last month and the 19th of this month.....but as soon as it hits the 20th of this month through the 31th of this month....it keeps showing the last period....which technically i am asking it to do.

What I need is.....When it becomes the 20th of this month....it starts a new report.

As I said.....the problem period is between the 20th and the end of the month.  Once the new month starts....everything is fine.

It somehow has to take into account when the report is being run.

Thanks.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Dave, I think that this may work for you.

```
    (
         (Day(GetDate()) > 19 and create_date between dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate()), 0) + 19 and dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate()), 0) + 18)
         or (Day(GetDate()) < 20 and create_date between dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate())-1, 0) + 19 and dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate())-1, 0) + 18)
    )
```

It essentially checks to see that the current day is greater than 19 and applies your current logic without subtracting a month.  I the current day is less than the 20th your current logic is applied.

Answer (score 0):

```
(
 DateTime >= CASE WHEN day(GETDATE()) >= 20 THEN 19 + dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate()), 0) ELSE 19 + dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0) END AND
 DateTime < CASE WHEN day(GETDATE()) >= 20 THEN 18 + dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate())+ 1, 0) ELSE 18 + dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate()), 0) END
)
```